# Datalist behavior changed

Tags: css, html, datalist

We had a datalist in our website which worked ok. 
But recently (without any knowledgable code changes) it started messing up in Firefox/IE/Edge, but still works perfect in Chrome.  Before it worked in every browser as it works in Chrome.

The code for the datalist looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <!--<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<?=lang("home_filter_where")?>" />-->
    <div class="input-group">
        <?php
        if (!empty($filterdata['location'])) {
            ?>
            <input id="location" name="location" type="text" list="locationList" autocomplete="off" value="<?php echo $filterdata['location']; ?>" class="form-control round-r">
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <input id="location" name="location" type="text" list="locationList" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Postcode of Gemeente" class="form-control round-r">
            <?php
        }
        ?>
        <div class="aListCon">
            <datalist id="locationList">
                <!--[if IE 9]><select disabled><![endif]-->
                <?php
                foreach ($citiesbe as $city) {
                    echo "<option value=\"$city->zip_code\">$city->name_nl";
                }
                ?>
                <!--[if IE 9]></select><![endif]-->
            </datalist>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

it can be seen from the following URL: 
https://www.giveaday.be/.
It is the search form on the homepage (we have this same field on a lot of pages, but the behavior is the same everywhere). 
If I open it in Chrome, it looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGH7v.jpg , but in Edge it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHREz.jpg , and on IE like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZg8r.jpg.

Please note that the screenshots is only when i type in the value of the datalist!
In Chrome (as expected) when I type in letters (so the text in the option), the results also show up, this is not happening in firefox/IE/Edge, only typing the value works there.

What has happened and how do I make the datalist work again as it worked before on chrome/ie/edge/firefox ?

Comment: are the browsers updated? one suggestion. First of all give dropdown a fixed height and it will scroll in that dropdown.

Comment: @nerdyDev we noticed this behavior just a couple of weeks ago. The browser could be the cause perhaps, but it is not only for us, for all the website visitors as well

Comment: well then there is no issue with your datalist. its only the browser issue.